# How does one declare a global variable in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

i expect some sarcasm but what the heck. i have searched the actionscript reference page and can't seem to find how to declare simple global variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of good answers already. I just want to point out that `YOU CAN` create global variables in AS3. Just create a file, for example, MyGlobal.as in root of your classes folder:

```
package {
    public var MyGlobal:String = "bla";
}
```

And you can access it as `MyGlobal` because it is in the top most package. This technique can be used in several not so destructive ways. For example you can have a global constant which is similar to a singleton but instead of being static it will be just an instance of some class:

```
package {
    public const MySingleton:IMySingleton = new MySingletonImpl();
}
```

---

Update; not from the original poster
I had never heard of this before so I put together a quick sample:

In the root directory:

```
package
{
    public var MyGlobal:String = "bla";
}
```

A test class:

```
package com.flextras.stackOverflow
{
    public class MyGlobalTest
    {
        public function MyGlobalTest()
        {
            trace(MyGlobal);
        }
    }
}
```

And the test application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" initialize="windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.flextras.stackOverflow.MyGlobalTest;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace(MyGlobal);
                var a :MyGlobalTest = new MyGlobalTest();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Run the app and the trace does indeed show up twice with the correct 'bla' value.

Comment: Glad someone mentioned the global variable syntax (:

Comment: Wow; I had no idea this was there.

Comment: Quite useful. Works nicely :)

Answer (score 4):

There are no global variables in as3. But static variables can be accessed without creating an instance of the class, so they can be used as global variables.

```
package 
{
     class MyClass
     {
         // ...
         public static var myStaticVar: Number;
         // ...
     }
}
```

Then any where in your program, you can access the variable myStaticVar like follows:

```
MyClass.myStaticVar = 5;
// ...
var value:Number = MyClass.myStaticVar;
```

Answer (score 3):

Global to what?

If you want to declare a variable which is "global" to a class; you can just use any variable:

```
public var myClassGlobal : Object = new Object();
```

This variable will be accessible anywhere inside the class; and because I made it public it is also available to any classes that can access an instance of that class.  You would access it like this:

```
trace(myClassInstance.myClassGlobal);
```

If you want to declare a variable which is "global" to a Flex Application, you can declare a variable in the main application file:

```
public var myFlexApplicationGlobal :Object = new Object():
```

You can access this value anywhere in your code using the [FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html#topLevelApplication).  Something like this:

```
trace((FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as myMainApplicationFile).myFlexApplicationGlobal);
```

An approach like this is generally considered an encapsulation no-no; because it gives your classes a dependency on the main application file and minimizes re-use.  That is generally something we try to avoid.

You could create a static variable and access it anywhere using the class.  Static variables are not tied to an instance of the class:

```
public static var myStaticGlobal :Object = new Object():
```

You would access it like this:

```
trace(MyClassWithStaticVariable.myStaticGlobal);
```

You could also create a Singleton class with your global variables and use a framework, such as Swiz or RobotLegs to inject that class into the classes that need it.  A quick google search should reveal you information on creating Singletons in Flex; and there is plenty of discussion for and against Singletons in the scope of the greater programming community..

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.appcloud9.utils
{
    public class GlobalReference
    {
        public static function get global() : Object
        {
            var getGlobal : Function = function() : Object
            {
                return this;
            };
            return getGlobal();
        }
    }
}

/*-|-||-|-||-|-||-  usage examples  -||-|-||-|-||-
 * the examples below focus on giving global access to the main Stage instance
 * but anything added to the global object ( which always exists no matter what )
 * is accessible via the same mechanisms
*/

// global stage reference added in main document class upon Event.EXIT_FRAME :
GlobalReference.global.stage = stage;

// later in a closure
var signalLightsOut = new Signal();
signalLightsOut.add( function() : void
{
    /* because the [ object global ] truly is 'global' all closures have
     * direct access to any properties added to it ( it is a dynamic class )
    */ 
    trace( stage );                        // [object Stage]
} );

// later in a constructor - before the class has a stage of it's own
public function MyConstructor()
{
    trace( stage );                        // null
    trace( GlobalReference.global.stage ); // [object Stage]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From within a method closure the keyword **`this`** returns a reference to the 'global' object.
Below are some interesting results when inspecting **`this`** from **inside a method closure**.

```
trace( this );    // outputs : [object global]

trace( flash.utils.describeType( this ) );

/* outputs :
description:
<type name="global" base="Object" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <constant name="Boolean" type="Boolean"/>
  <constant name="Namespace" type="Namespace"/>
  <constant name="undefined" type="*"/>
  <constant name="Number" type="Number"/>
  <constant name="USE_ITRAITS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="Vector" type="__AS3__.vec::Vector" uri="__AS3__.vec"/>
  <constant name="uint" type="uint"/>
  <constant name="Infinity" type="Number"/>
  <constant name="int" type="int"/>
  <constant name="String" type="String"/>
  <constant name="Object" type="Object"/>
  <constant name="HIDE_NSURI_METHODS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_BASES" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="Array" type="Array"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_VARIABLES" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_ACCESSORS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_INTERFACES" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_METHODS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_METADATA" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_CONSTRUCTOR" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="INCLUDE_TRAITS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="Class" type="Class"/>
  <constant name="HIDE_OBJECT" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="FLASH10_FLAGS" type="uint" uri="avmplus"/>
  <constant name="AS3" type="*"/>
  <constant name="Function" type="Function"/>
  <constant name="NaN" type="Number"/>
  <method name="parseInt" declaredBy="global" returnType="Number">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="int" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="parseFloat" declaredBy="global" returnType="Number">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="escape" declaredBy="global" returnType="String">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="unescape" declaredBy="global" returnType="String">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="isXMLName" declaredBy="global" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="describeType" declaredBy="global" returnType="XML" uri="avmplus">
    <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="uint" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getQualifiedClassName" declaredBy="global" returnType="String" uri="avmplus">
    <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="getQualifiedSuperclassName" declaredBy="global" returnType="String" uri="avmplus">
    <parameter index="1" type="*" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="decodeURI" declaredBy="global" returnType="String">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="decodeURIComponent" declaredBy="global" returnType="String">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="encodeURI" declaredBy="global" returnType="String">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="encodeURIComponent" declaredBy="global" returnType="String">
    <parameter index="1" type="String" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="isNaN" declaredBy="global" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  </method>
  <method name="isFinite" declaredBy="global" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  </method>
</type>:
*/

description = flash.utils.describeType( Object( this ).constructor as Class );
trace( "description:\n" + description );

/* outputs :
<type name="Object" base="Class" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="true">
  <extendsClass type="Class"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <constant name="length" type="int"/>
  <accessor name="prototype" access="readonly" type="*" declaredBy="Class"/>
  <factory type="Object"/>
</type>:
*/
```