# Global variables in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm new in action script 3. I intend to use global variable.

Here some way to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505141/how-does-one-declare-a-global-variable-in-actionscript) and [this](http://zanuzawa.blogspot.ru/2012/01/global-variables-in-actionscript-3-as3.html)

I download simple banner from [here](http://www.web-article.com.ua/2009/actionscript-3-sdelat-flash-banner-ssylkoj/)

Create file Globe.as in the same directory as test_banner_actionscript_3.fla. Globe.cs contains next code

```
package 
{
  public class Main 
  {
     public static var myPencil:Number = 3;
  }
}
```

banner code looks like this

```
mybanlink.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mybanlinkClickListener);

function mybanlinkClickListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(Main.myPencil); //3
    var url:String="http://www.web-article.com.ua";
    var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(url);
    navigateToURL(urlRequest);
}
```

but I get

```
error: 1120: Access of undefined property Main
```

Interesting that Intellisense suggests "myPencil" when typing "Main."

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly forgot `import Main` in the begin of your banner code. Remember, when you use a class, always check that this class is imported.

Comment: `import` is for packages. I use anonymous package as suggested in [stack suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505141/how-does-one-declare-a-global-variable-in-actionscript). And what if I don't use class and using just `package {
    public var MyGlobal:String = "bla";
}`

Comment: After try manually your code, are you sure that your Main.as file is the same folder than your fla ? It actually works correctly here.

Comment: In described case renaming Globe.as to Main.as actually helps.

Comment: Is it possible make to work `package { public var MyGlobal:String = "bla"; }` case ?